# how to make a class made inside symfony 1.4 accessible to an external php script

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, autoloader

i have an external php script, to carry out CRUD functionality via an already existing model in symfony 1.4 framework.what i originally thought to acomplish was to require the auto load files and the internal class would load automatically these are the files i thought that will resolve the issue.but it didn't

```
require '/var/www/html/orangehrm/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoload.class.php';
require '/var/www/html/orangehrm/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfAutoloadAgain.class.php';

require '/var/www/html/orangehrm/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';

require '/var/www/html/orangehrm/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfSimpleAutoload.class.php';
```

im looking for a way to auto load the internal models and classes from symfony before the external script execute without directly using require on the files

Comment: i couldn't find the auto loaders but the work around is to require the index.php file in symfony/web folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't find the auto loaders but the work around is to require the index.php file in symfony/web folder .this will load the files like in the normal case.this is just a work around.any other answers are excepted.